# Why does Websocket work faster for bigger messages and more user connected to server?

Tags: json, performance, websocket, message, stomp

I have created performance tests for websocket ( + STOMP message format) and i got strange results from it. I got smaller request time for bigger messages and also for more connected users which send messages in the same frequency (about 47 messages per second). Message has about 120 bytes.

There are a charts which present my results(User is added for every 10 seconds of communication(10 users at the end)):

[image]

Only 1 user:
[image]

There are configuration for client and server:
lib: "@stomp/stompjs": "^5.4.4"

```
this.stompClient = new Client({
        brokerURL: this.serverUrl,
        splitLargeFrames: true,
        reconnectDelay: 1000,
        heartbeatIncoming: 4000,
        heartbeatOutgoing: 4000
    });
```

On server side is default config for webscoket Stomp spring
Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Controller(catch messages):

```
    @MessageMapping("/send/position")
public void updatePositionForPlayer(Player player, Principal user, @Header("requestTimestamp") Long requestTimestamp) {
....
}
```

Send response:

```
    @Override
public void sendToUser(String destination, GameObject gameObject, HeaderStatus status,
                       String userSession, long requestTimestamp) {
    this.template.convertAndSendToUser(userSession, destination, gameObject, Map.of(
            "requestTimestamp", requestTimestamp,
            "status", status
    ));
}
```

Comment: What message broker are you using?

Comment: I am using default, in-memory broker provided by spring dependency (Simple broker). https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html .